# Delimiter not working on MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, delimiter

I need to utilize two insert statements in a single procedure in order to update a master and detail table, so I'm trying to use the delimiter keyword for this to work. I'm using phpMyAdmin 3.5.8, client libmysql - 5.0.96, and mysql 5.1.70. I've tried all sorts of syntax, but none seem to work. This is my query:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `agregarPrincipio` (IN ID_PRODUCTO INT UNSIGNED, IN DESCR VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `TM_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO` (`DESCRIPCION`) VALUES(DESCR);
INSERT INTO TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO(`ID_TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`,`ID_TM_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`) VALUES(ID_PRODUCTO,LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT; 
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Any ideas on what may be happening?

Comment: MYSQL 5.1 is quite old. Did you consider to upgrade to MySQL 5.5 or MariaDB 5.5?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. This is just a problem with the syntax? What's the error message? Which client are you using to access to your RDBMS? Remember `DELIMITER` is not an SQL statement, but just a MySQL CLI statement -- and so only available if using that program.

Comment: The error I get... #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 7

Comment: the problem is in the line `INSERT INTO TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO(`ID_TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`,`ID_TM_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`) VALUES(ID_PRODUCTO,LAST_INSERT_ID());`. You are trying to directly call a stored procedure `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your second select statement. If `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a single value, try to save it in a variable. Then use that variable

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the line

```
INSERT INTO TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO(`ID_TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`,`ID_TM_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`) VALUES(ID_PRODUCTO,LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

. You are trying to directly call a stored procedure `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your second select statement. If `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a single value, try to save it in a variable. Then use that variable

```
DECLARE last_id int default 0;
SET last_id= SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); #if it is a function other wise use exec
INSERT INTO TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO(`ID_TD_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`,`ID_TM_PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO`) VALUES(ID_PRODUCTO,last_id);
```